# How do I detect if a Windows device is touch-enabled

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, touchscreen

How do I detect if a device is touch-enabled in C# for a WinForms app (Not WPF).

- I found information on `GetSystemMetrics`. But I can't find how to use this in C#.
- I tried using `System.Windows.Input.Tablet` class. But it's not coming up in C#, even though I am using .NET Framework 4.5.
- I tried using `System.Windows.Devices`. But it's not coming up in C#, even though I am using .NET Framework 4.5.
- I have also checked [Detect whether a Windows 8 Store App has a touch screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12664228/) and [How to detect a touch enabled device (Win 8, C#.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14898376/), which would seem to make this question a duplicate.  However, neither of these answers my question.

Answer (score 17):

`GetSystemMetrics` seems to be the right way to go. It should be accessed through P/Invoke like this:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);

public static bool IsTouchEnabled()
{
     const int MAXTOUCHES_INDEX = 95;
     int maxTouches = GetSystemMetrics(MAXTOUCHES_INDEX);

     return maxTouches > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101316/determine-metro-app-is-running-in-windows-8-tab-or-desktop-pc)

```
var hasTouch = Windows.Devices.Input
              .PointerDevice.GetPointerDevices()
              .Any(p => p.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Touch);
```

Comment: As taken from my question....Windows.Devices is not coming up in c#/.Net 4.5 in VS2012Ultimate

Comment: Your question said "System.Windows.Input.Tablet". I'm not using that namespace... If this isn't working, can you clarify what you mean by "not coming up" ? No intellisense? Doesn't compile? What's the compiler error?

Comment: I tried System.Windows.Input.Tablet AND System.Windows.Devices.  Neither of these are being allowed.  No Intellisense...not compiling...not showing up in Object browser...Underlined in red in VS

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative but "not being allowed" is not a technical description of the problem. Are you getting compiler errors? If so, what are they? Have you added a reference to the `System.Windows.Input` namespace? (Right-click project, Add Reference)

Comment: "System.Windows.Input" is not showing up as an available namespace.  Only "System.Windows.Input.Manipulations"

Comment: I think (although I'm not 100% positive) that `Windows.Devices.Input` is marshalling `WinRT` and I don't think it's available for `Win32` apps.

Comment: In fact, if you check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.devices.input.pointerdevice.aspx, on "Requirements" it clearly says `Windows Store Apps Only`. This answer is clearly wrong (the linked answer is for `metro apps`)

Comment: FYI if possible, make sure you reference the assembly....not all assemblies are referenced OOB but do check to see if it is supported on the platform in question

Comment: Ahmed: When I browse for the assembly, not finding System.Windows.Input or System.Windows.Devices.

Comment: JCL:  Then, in other words, Microsoft, in their infinite wisdom, has not created a way to detect a touch-enabled device in Win32/Winforms applications?

Comment: @RickInWestPalmBeach notice the namespace doesn't necessarily match the assembly name where it's defined (i.e., the namespace could be `System.Windows.Input` but it could be defined in `MyInputBindings.dll`).

Comment: @RickInWestPalmBeach I absolutely didn't say that: I don't know the answer to the question (or else I'd be answering it)... it's more likely possible. What I said is that the way this answer (the one we are commenting) proposes is wrong, since it's for Windows Store apps, and not for WinForms apps like you are requesting.

Comment: Related: I love @HighCore's comment on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25394291/2589202) question

Comment: I just found this in the MSDN:  System.Windows.Input provides types to support the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) input system. This includes device abstraction classes for mouse, keyboard, and stylus devices, a common input manager class, support for commanding and custom commands, and various utility classes.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145013%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: If you want to use `System.Windows.Input`, you need to reference `PresentationCore.dll` on your project (that's the WPF main library). I would advise against this if you are doing WinForms, since there are many class names that collide and namespacing can be confusing... there's nothing preventing you to do it, but my recommendation is that you don't mix the two (at least, not in the same project)

Comment: You can use this, which uses the Win32 api: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5957751/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-system-is-touch-enabled

Comment: JCL: Already tried this...Could not find how to use GetSystemMetrics.

Comment: @RickInWestPalmBeach when in doubt with using any Win32 function in .NET, I recommend http://pinvoke.net . In this case, check: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getsystemmetrics

Comment: @JCL: I got it to work with GetSystemMetrics from pinvoke!  Thanks!