# How to detect Touch Screen display with Inno setup?

Tags: inno-setup

How to detect if Touch Screen display is available with Innosetup script?

Is the best method to use `GetSystemMetrics(MAXTOUCHES_INDEX)` ?

Comment: Inno Setup does not have an API to detect a touch screen. So if you are asking what is the best Windows API to detect a touch screen, then it indeed seems to be `GetSystemMetrics(MAXTOUCHES_INDEX)` – [How do I detect if a Windows device is touch-enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27803965/850848).