# How do I detect if a device is touch-enabled in c# for a WinForms app on Windows Embedded Standard 7

Tags: c#, winforms, touch

Below code works fine on Windows 7 but not on Windows Embedded Standard 7 :

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int nIndex);

    public static bool isTouchEnabled()
    {
        int MAXTOUCHES_INDEX = 0x95;
        int maxTouches = GetSystemMetrics(MAXTOUCHES_INDEX);

        return maxTouches > 0;
    }
```

Comment: in WinUser.h the value is #define SM_MAXIMUMTOUCHES 95 decimal, not hexadecimal 0x95

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var hasTouch = Windows.Devices.Input
              .PointerDevice.GetPointerDevices()
              .Any(p => p.PointerDeviceType == Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDeviceType.Touch);
```

For more check this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101316/determine-metro-app-is-running-in-windows-8-tab-or-desktop-pc)

Comment: for Windows.Devices.Input.PointerDevice.GetPointerDevices() Minimum supported client is Windows 8 [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br225637)